# Searching cell for string and return index number

Tags: matlab

I have a 20 x 2 cell. Both columns contains strings. What I would like to do is search for a string in column two and where the value in column 2 matches my search string to return the value in column 1. Please see my example below - I believe it will make things clearer.

```
name         region          
ABC          USA
ASD          EU
PLKDD        EU
ERT          EU
LKK          ASIA
MNN          USA
WER          EU
```

The result I would like based on the search string being "EU" is below

```
result
ASD
PLKDD
ERT
WER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
x = 
    'ABC'      'USA' 
    'ASD'      'EU'  
    'PLKDD'    'EU'  
    'ERT'      'EU'  
    'LKK'      'ASIA'
    'MNN'      'USA' 
    'WER'      'EU'  

y = x(find(ismember(x(:,2), 'EU')),1)   
y = 
    'ASD'
    'PLKDD'
    'ERT'
    'WER'
```