# search for string in cell and return index number

Tags: matlab

I have a 20 x 2 cell. Both columns contains strings. What I would like to do is search for a string in column two and where the value in column 2 matches my search string to return the index number.

```
name         region          
ABC          USA
ASD          EU
PLKDD        EU
ERT          EU
LKK          ASIA
MNN          USA
WER          EU
```

The result I would like based on the search string being "EU" is below

```
result
2
3
4
7
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching cell for string and return index number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392658/searching-cell-for-string-and-return-index-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `strcmp` and `find`.

```
index = find(strcmp(value(:, 2), 'EU'))
```